# AJAX call with parameters not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've got troubles making an ajax post with parameters to my controller. While this works:

```
$.post("../api/vorgang/blubb");
```

```csharp
[HttpPost]
[Route(@"blubb")]
public void blubb()
{
    // do amazing things here
}
```

The method is not being hit when I extend it for parameters:

```
$.post("../api/vorgang/blubb", { param1: "param1", param2: "param2"} );
```

```csharp
[HttpPost]
[Route(@"blubb")]
public void blubb(string param1, string param2)
{
    // method is not hit, why oh why
}
```

```text
// the request text
param1=param1&param2=param2
```

I see that it results in

> 404: "no HTTP-Resource could be found that fits the URI http://localhost:49412/api/vorgang/blubb.

I have tried changing the ajax call to

```
$.post("../api/vorgang/blubb", JSON.stringify({ 
    param1: "param1", 
    param2: "param2"
}));
```

this changes the request text to

```
{"param1":"param1","param2":"param2"}
```

but the controller still does not get hit.

I'd be thankful for a hint!

Comment: @HarshadVekariya - That'll make no difference. That second argument is a JavaScript object whose property names need not be quoted (unlike a JSON string).

Comment: @HarshadVekariya Putting quotes around the key makes ZERO difference. An object is an object.

Comment: Yes, it did not make any difference :o)

Comment: Is your controller `api` controller?

Comment: Yes it is an 'api' controller

Comment: Hmm it's working when I'm using an MVC Controller instead of an ApiController.

Comment: Have you verified that your ApiController is waiting at "/api/vorgang"?  See if you can hit a GET method for that controller (or create a test one to try).  I've had this problem before, and it's usually ended up in how the ApiController was bound/mapped to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are passing parameter's with `HttpPost`, I am not sure if it's gonna work. Was going thru [FromBody](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) approach mentioned here.

Alternatively, you could try creating a Model object and let the MVC do the heavy lifting.

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void blubb(Parameters param1)
    {
        // method is not hit, why oh why
    }
}
public class Parameters
{
    public string param1 { get; set; }
    public string param2 { get; set; }
}
```

Your AJAX call:

```
var _parameters = {
    param1: "param1",
    param2: "param2"
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/Test/blubb",
    cache: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(_parameters),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) { console.log("Success"); }
});
```

Final Result :

[image]

Not sure, how much will it help!